# Strange behaviour using String.Replace

Tags: c#

I used replace keyword to replace string or char, and i can replace successfully
here is my code

```
string keywoord = "Emerika";
var result = keywoord.Replace(keywoord[0], 'A');
```

**the result** : Amerika

but i get strange behaviour when replace thing and the next thing is same

```
 string keywoord = "xxxxx";
    var result = keywoord.Replace(keywoord[0], 'A');
```

**I will get result : AAAAA**

**It should return Axxxx**

```
string keywoord = "aaakaaa";
      var result = keywoord.Replace(keywoord[0], 'z');
```

**I will get result : zzzkzzz**

**It should return zaakaaa**

so what happened with this,  i just need to replace one thing not multiple thing, any error or do u have another solution?

Comment: Why do you expect that `Replace('x', 'A');` will replace only one occurrence?

Comment: keyword[0] = a
So you're replacing all a with z

Comment: no keyword[0] mean that i replace only first

Comment: @Progman i think it occure one because it's not looping

Comment: @NurMahin, The first parameter you're passing to `Replace` is the character you want to search and replace, not the position in the string that you want to replace.

Comment: @Mikael i just one replace first index, why replace acts as loop

Comment: @NurMahin I'm not sure why you're arguing, look up how .Replace works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8

You're basically saying -- Replace all occurrences of keyword[0] (which is a) with z. It's performing as intended.

Comment: @NimrodDolev is it ? i have just known, how can solve it ?

Comment: The definition of [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) is: Returns a new string in which _all_ occurrences of a specified Unicode character in this instance are replaced with another specified Unicode character.

Comment: yes you are right , how to specify the position @Mikael

Comment: i think it not answer and duplicate i want to replace something with another based on positon also, how ?

Comment: @devNull how can i use replace is it possible ?

Comment: Is your intention to just replace the first character in the string (whatever it is) by another character? Then e.g. `var sb = new StringBuilder(keywoord); sb[0] = 'A'; result = sb.ToString();` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the first n apparitions you can use Regex.

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("o"));
var newText = regex.Replace("Hello World", "Foo", 1);
```

//result HellFoo World

- "o" is the text witch you want to replace with
- "Hello World" is the text in which you want to make changes
- "Foo" is the replacement
- 1(the third parameter) is the number of replacements(the first n occurrences to replace)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to understand -

1. Some `Replace` implementations, for example in JavaScript, only replace the first occurrence of the searched string. The C# implementations do not, it replaces *ANY* occurrence, so if you replace every `"x"` in `"xxxx"` with an `"A"`, you get `"AAAA"`.
2. The first parameter you pass to `Replace` is the value that you want to look for, and the second parameter is the value you want to replace it with.

See these examples -

```
"Emerika".Replace('E', 'A'); // "America"
"Emerika".Replace('k', 'A'); // "EmeriAa"
"Emerika".Replace('x', 'A'); // "Emerika", because there is no 'x' to replace
"xxxx".Replace('g', 'a'); // "xxxx", becuase there is no 'g' to replace
"xxxx".Replace('x', 'A'); // "AAAA", becuase every 'x' was replaced with an 'A'

var str = "Emerika";
str.Replace(str[0], 'A'); // "America", but just because the value of str[0] is equal to 'E', so this is just like out first example.
```

Here's a link to the [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) for `String.Replace` with some more explanations